# Cannot explain strange behavior of this simple program

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

It is the first program I write in NASM assembly. The following code reads two 32bit integers from stdin and prints them to stdout using C libraries. It's a sort of echo.

```
global main

extern scanf
extern printf

segment .text
main:
    ; read first number
    push numa
    push in_f
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    ; read second number
    push numb
    push in_f
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    ; move numbers to registers
    mov eax, [numa]
    mov ebx, [numb]

    ; print first number
    push eax
    push out_f
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    ; print second number
    push ebx
    push out_f
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    ; exit
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

segment .rodata
in_f: db '%d', 0
out_f: db '%d', 10, 0

segment .bss
numa: resw 1
; discard: resw 1 <- uncomment to make this code work!
numb: resw 1
```

However it doesn't work. Here's a sample input:

```
1
2
```

And its output:

```
131073
2
```

The second number is always printed correctly, while the first one is never displayed correctly (unless the second number is zero)! It seems that the second number interfere with the first one. Indeed when I allocate some words of empty space between the two numbers in BSS segment, the program works successfully (i.e. just uncomment the penultimate line and the program works).

What's wrong with my program?

PS: I'm not interested in other solutions, I only want to understand why the above code has this strange behavior.

Comment: change resw to resd for both vars.  the stack is dword aligned not word

Comment: Wouldn't become 64bit (32bit * 2 words) integers?

Comment: Ah ok, got it! Intel calls "word" 16bit, so dword is 32bit. Now it's all clear. Thanks!